# How to restrict screen recording in iOS devices in Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am developing an app in Flutter, which I need to restrict screen recording in iOS devices.
What I have done now is checking for the UIScreen.main.isCaptured flag in the AppDelegate and checking it frequently using a timer in my dart file.

Is there a better way to do this by making use of capturedDidChangeNotification from apple, so that I don't have to run a timer and the dart file get notified when the screen recording status changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add `capturedDidChangeNotification` observer on [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) and push the result to FlutterEventChannel. Then on Dart side you setup [EventChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html), which has `receiveBroadcastStream` method that returns a Stream than you can listen to. To be sure to handle closing Streams both on iOS part and Flutter.

You can checkout these official example with listening to battery charging, which is almost the same (NotificationCenter + Streams):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/platform_channel_swift/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/platform_channel_swift/lib/main.dart

Comment: Do we have to close the streams when disposed or will it be closed when the widgets are removed.

Comment: In Flutter, you have to cancel streams manually fe. in dispose override of State to avoid memory leaks. If you always listen to stream in the app, you should in theory be fine without canceling it, but I would do that anyway, because in practice, some parts of the app may get fully reloaded without clearing the memory by the system.

Answer (score 0):

there's a new plugin to listen the changes of screen recording for iOS.
[flutter_prevent_screen_recording](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_prevent_screen_recording). With this plugin you can be able to know if the screen is being recorded, and you can stop the task, or show something like show dialog, with text of turning the screen recorder off.